# Ember Each loop rerendering entire array of objects when the array is updated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using `Ember 1.13.15`.

I have an array of objects (contains nested objects) which is iterated using each loop and is passed to a child component.

```
//parent.hbs

{{#each configData as |item index|}}

    {{ my-child
        childId=(concat item.name index)
        childName= item.name
        childColor=item.color
        childEnabled=item.enabled
        actionUpdateParent='action1'
    }}
```

And the following observer inside the component

```
//parent.js

configDataObserver: function(){

    var configData = this.get('configDataFromSource');

    this.set( 'configData' , configData );

}.observes('configDataFromSource'),
```

Now, whenever any object inside `configData` array gets updated, the `each` loop runs through the entire array and all child components gets redrawn causing serious performance issues.

I found similar questions, but none of them provides a clear solution. Please help.

Comment: You replace the whole object here: `this.set( 'configData' , configData );`. In this situation redrawing the whole thing is correct - ember does not know what specific element was changed. Using ArrayProxy and updating [specific element](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/classes/ArrayProxy/methods/replace?anchor=replace) might help (although I didn't test such scenario myself).

Comment: @GennadyDogaev, yes I knew I was replacing the entire object, I just wanted know if there is any Ember way to update an array easily without actually replacing it. I will go through your suggestion though, Thanks!

Comment: I tried and found @NullVoxPopuli's solution works magically! Here's what is wrtitten in the guides: "The key option is used to tell Ember how to determine if the array being iterated over with {{#each}} has changed between renders. By helping Ember detect that some elements in the array are the same, DOM elements can be re-used, significantly improving rendering speed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to set the key in the each.

Like this:

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/if?anchor=each

```
{{#each configData key="name" as |item index|}}
```

Comment: You've saved me from a long headache. I added `key` to just about every element I could think of to no avail but didn't know a key should be added to the loop itself. :)